# What is this (HTML)

Tags: html, css

```
    <header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Articles</a>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
```

And CSS no "`.`"

```
header {}

nav {}
```

As I can see, there is `<header></header>` and `<nav></nav>`

Lets say if my website has 2 `nav` section how to implement two different CSS?

In advance, thanks.

Comment: I think you need to learn a little about applying a class or an ID to a web page

Comment: Those were `html5` don't you think its rocking.

Answer (score 0):

Give each `nav` a specific class or id

like

```
<nav id="first_nav"></nav>
```

CSS

```
#first_nav{

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

They are html5 elements.

> HTML5 is the latest evolution of the standard that defines HTML. The term represents two different concepts:
>
> It is a new version of the language HTML, with new elements, attributes, and behaviors,
>       and a larger set of technologies that allows more diverse and powerful Web sites and applications. This set is sometimes called HTML5 & friends and often shortened to just HTML5.

[see more info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5)

---

As if you have more than one element such like as `nav` then you could use its parent and the nav itself to get the selector more specific:

```
header nav{}
footer nav{}
```